# Unattended Eclipse update

Tags: eclipse, unattended, auto-updates

I have to update my Eclipse frequently via "Check for Update" or "Install new Software" and looking for more convenient way than doing it by hand.

Some sort of unattended batch file starting eclipse using ease to trigger the update check.

Has anybody done that before, or could imagine it could work. If so I would like hints to work on a solution.

Comment: On Ubuntu, if Eclipse is installed from the repository, it will be updated automatically, together with other installed software in the periodic update checks.

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I install Eclipse from a command line?

You can use [install-eclipse](https://github.com/budhash/install-eclipse) as a starting point:

> **Introduction**
>
> install-eclipse is a shell script that installs eclipse in a
>   non-interactive, automated way. As part of the workflow, the script
>   install the Eclipse Platform Runtime Binaries and then installs
>   additional eclipse plugin(s), if specified. The list of plugins to be
>   installed can either be a specified via:
>
> - command-line switch. e.g. -p "http://beust.com/eclipse/,org.testng.eclipse"
> - local or remote config file, listing the plugins to be installed. Refer to git-java-mvn.cfg, as an example.
>
> See Usage and Examples for more details.
>
> **Features**
>
> - non-interactive eclipse installation, great for automated setups
> - installs only what is needed
> - ability to provide a list of plugins to be installed.
> - the plugin list can be a remote file accessible over http[s]
> - optimizes eclipse.ini [EXPERIMENTAL]

Source [budhash/install-eclipse: non-interactive eclipse installer](https://github.com/budhash/install-eclipse)

---

#### Further Reading

- [silent/scripted install eclipse patch/plugin help - Jazz Forum](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/96253/silentscripted-install-eclipse-patchplugin-help)